# issues with clone and for loop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
private void buildDeck(ArrayList<Card> Monsters, ArrayList<Card> Spells) {

    int monstersQouta = 15;
    int spellsQouta = 5;

    Random r = new Random();

    for (; monstersQouta > 0; monstersQouta--) {

        int randomIndex = r.nextInt(monsters.size());
        MonsterCard monster = (MonsterCard) monsters.get(randomIndex);

        MonsterCard clone = new MonsterCard(monster.getName(),
                monster.getDescription(), monster.getLevel(),
                monster.getAttackPoints(), monster.getDefensePoints());
        clone.setMode(monster.getMode());
        clone.setHidden(monster.isHidden());
        clone.setLocation(Location.DECK);
        deck.add(clone);

    }
```

I need to know why we used here `clone()`
and how this for loop in this code works

Comment: `clone()` is not being used. It just so happens that the variable is called `clone`, but that has no semantic importance to the code.

Comment: so can I use monster variable instead of clone to achieve same purpose

Comment: Probably not, but it very much depends upon how you use the `MonsterCard` instances. `MonsterCard` is clearly mutable, so any calls with side effects you make (e.g. `clone.setMode(...)`) would be updating these fields on an existing instance; creating the defensive copy `clone` allow you to make the changes without affecting the existing instances.

Comment: how this for loop differs from  the normal for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy Turner said for your first question :

> clone() is not being used. It just so happens that the variable is called clone, but that has no semantic importance to the code.

Concerning the `for` statement he's composed of 3 parts ,each separated by one `;` , and none of them is obligated to be there :

- The first part is where you can, or not, declare your incremental variable : `int i = 0;`
- The second part is where you must put an evaluation resulting on a boolean value : `kappa.lengh >= i;`
- The thrid part is where you will modify the variable(s) values : `i--;`

Since none of these parts are obligated, you could write a correct for loop like this one : `for(;;)`.

Here's a link to the documentation : [For statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).